# MySQL Error, what does it mean

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update two columns in a xref database. I am getting this error message:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`globaldetroit`.`org_cult_xref`, CONSTRAINT `org_cult_xref_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`org_id`) REFERENCES `organization` (`org_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

I want to be able to have a many-many relationship, and these errors seem to prevent me from having one.

EDIT:

That is very odd! There most certainly is a column org_id with the value of "6" (as an integer) in the table organization! I just checked!

Comment: It's protecting you from yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set a value that has a foreign key constrant -- ie the key does not exist in the foreign table.

So `globaldetroit's` `org_cult_xref` references an `org_id` in `organization` that does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

you're putting in field `globaldetroit`.`org_cult_xref` value not existing in `organization`.`org_id`

Answer (score 1):

Many-many relationship is bad, don't go there.

Your error seems to be caused because the row you insert in org_cult_xref has a column org_id and the value you insert there cannot be found in the organization table.

Comment: Can you expand on this?  M:M are frequently required and as far as I know are not a problem.

Comment: M:N is invalid in SQL - use a table to combine them. Say we build a weblog: we have a table with tags and a table with posts. A post can have multiple tags and a tag doesn't necessarily belong to a single post. This is a M:N relationship. Define a post_has_tag table with a primary key (post_id,tag_id). Then when you tag something, simply use this table. I suppose you can call this a M:1:N solution.

Comment: Adding to that: in MySQL Workbench, when you try to create a M:N relation (using the button that says M:N), it will automatically create this table for you.

Comment: I realise that we usually build a 1:MM:1 thing in reality, but isn't that like saying "doing this impossible thing is not possible" - This is probably not the place to discuss this, I was just curious how one builds an M:M *without* the intermediary table at all.

Comment: Well, it may not be entirely impossible, but you can't use foreign keys such as the ones you're using on this table.

Answer (score 0):

You have a foreign key defined on the table you are trying to insert/update into, which basically says the value in `org_id` should exist in the `organization`  table, and it is not the case.